# Grails - How to unit test a service that uses a simple HTTP utility function?

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I wrote an simple HTTP utility class, which takes a HTTP method name and a requesting URL then return the response.

In my Grails app, several Services will use this utility to get results of some Web API calls. However, I don't know how to unit test these Services. The utility is so simple that it only uses `HttpURLConnection` to execute HTTP requests, no any other dependencies.

How should I unit test these Services? Should I make the utility as a property of the Services, so that this utility can be injected and mocked on them?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a MockHttpUtility, and then use it for test environment.

You can modify resources.groovy so that for tests, the mockService will be injected in your services/controllers instead of real service.

```
switch(GrailsUtil.environment) {
  case "test":
        httpUtil(MockHttpUtil) {bean ->
            bean.autowire = "byName"
        }
  }
```

This would work for integration tests.

For unit tests, you can define the mock service as below

```
void testFoo() {
  defineBeans {
    httpUtil(MockHttpUtil)
 }
}
```

You can design mock http util such that it returns the expected response when called. Eg, you can have a constructor or a setter that will take the expected response, and when the utility method is called with http method and url, it will return the given response.